# Unusual conjugation of "to be"

Tags: verbs, british-english, slang, dialects, conjugation

I encountered several times a certain type of sentences (in colloquial contexts) which were clearly grammatically incorrect but seems to be widely spread and, as a non-native English speaker, I would have liked to have more information about that.

It is about the conjugation of the modal verb *to be*. I have heard many times the following type of sentences:

- *"We was playing basketball"*
- *"They was eating dinner"*
- *"I were there"*
- *"He were with me"*

where the last two were used without any conditional of any sort. These sentences are obviously wrong in standard English (as far as I know) but still seem widely used in everyday life conversations. Therefore, my question was the following:

How wrong are these grammatical structures ? How strange will I sound if I use them ? Also, is it some kind of dialect/slang and in what kind of context do we use them?

Unfortunately I do not have any neat example to provide for I've heard it in an everyday life conversation with my office mates who are from Scotland. (I did not dare to ask them directly as I barely understand when they speak)

If someone could provide me more information about them I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you provide links to where you found these examples? The first two, at least, are likely AAVE.

Comment: See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603575/girls-is-or-are-from-the-song-players-by-coi-leray

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any neat example to provide for I've heard it in an everyday life conversation with my office mates who are from Scotland. (I did not dare to ask them directly as I barely understand when they speak)

Comment: Ah. This may be something specific to Scottish English. (I'm guessing they weren't speaking Scots, which would be far less comprehensible.)

Comment: The usages are not unusual among folks in the US who are from poor backgrounds, though they'd be rare among reasonably well-educated middle-class folks.

Comment: Your Scottish colleagues are not well representative of  usage in Scotland. I have wide geographical experience in Scotland (where I live) and never hear this usage among educated folk, rarely elsewhere here. You will hear the usage in some sections of society in south-east England, London and the south-west, where it may be consistently used. Do not use it unless you wish to pose as poorly educated.

Comment: @alphabet your speculation that this is peculiar to Scotland is simply wrong.

Comment: There many, many places where speakers of English don't follow the singular/plural rule for verbs. This is dialectically correct, 100%. I am sure in your native language similar things occur. They happen in all the languages I speak (four).

Comment: Also, _be_ is always an auxiliary verb, is the only verb in English inflected for singular/plural agreement, is the only verb in English inflected for first person singular, and has by far the most complex paradigm and set of idiomatic usages of any verb. Many linguists hesitate to call it a verb, since it's so bizarre.

Comment: The use in the third and fourth examples is common in Yorkshire, where I live. I do not know anywhere where the pattern in the first and second is common, though I believe there are such places.

Answer (score 1):

> These sentences are obviously wrong in standard English

If we realise that "standard English" cannot be defined but is merely a convenient phrase to express the theoretical idea that there is one English to which everyone must aspire, then the idea of "non-standard" becomes equally theoretical.

The first thing to observe is that nobody, in any language, speaks the perfect, "standard version" 100% of the time.

The next thing to note is that although increasing wealth and the printing press led towards a levelling (standardisation?) of the language, up until the era of mass communication (say, c. 1900) dialects and regionalisms dominated the spoken language and were considered normal within the region. These arose from the dialects (or even languages) of Old English in which the verb "to be" and its constituents varied massively.

"I were there" is merely a dialect version of the conjugation of "to be" and we also have "I **wen't** be threp by a bairn like thoo." [I **will not be** rebuked by a child like you/thee/thou.]*(1877   E. Peacock Gloss. Words Manley & Corringham, Lincs. (at cited word 'threap'))* that are standard within an area.